# What should I say "Do not step on your spit!"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[spit](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spit_2)**: [uncountable] the liquid that is produced in your mouth SYNONYM
>   saliva

Ok, my little child has just been fed some food. Now, he spat some out onto the floor. I don't want him to step on the food that he has just spat out on the floor.

What should I say "**Do not step on your spit!**"?

But "**spit**" (noun) means saliva, not the food that you have just spat out.

Or do I have to be wordy like this "**Do not step on the food that you have just spat out**"?

Comment: *Don't step in the mess*?

Comment: I can imagine a parent saying "Don't step in it!" without having to give a name to the mess on the floor.

Comment: It looks to me like the "do not step" part of the this question is extraneous and that you're really asking about what to call the food that's been spat out.  Is that right?

Comment: @Juhasz, yes, is there a technical name for the food that has been spat out?